# windows 95 virtualization and CPU idle

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

We are in the situation that we need to migrate our windows 95 systems (i know, that is so last century ). There is no hardware for a reasonable price available to run our windows 95 systems. So we are extending the overdue lifetime of it, by making them virtual.

Now we see that VMware reports 100% CPU utilization of a windows 95 VM. This is because windows 95 doesn't know how to manage a CPU.
For this reason software like rain or Waterfall, or CPUCool are introduced. The they are sending a HLT instruction to the CPU. This causes the CPU to halt and wait for new triggers to work.

I've tested the mentioned programs in the VM, but they don't work, but generate errors.

anyone has a valid workaround, solution ??

btw. I know that the best solutiuon is to replace the windows95 with windows XP. But in our situation that will take at least 5 years. Our windows 95 systems are running factory process control software.....

Comment: how does support for this control software work as the OS was OEL'ed a long time ago?

Comment: also have you installed the vmtools into the VM? what version of ESX are you using?

Comment: "There is no hardware for a reasonable price available" - I bet I could go to the tip and get some for free

Comment: @Chopper3 - "how does support for this control software work as the OS was OEL'ed a long time ago?" i didn't get what does it mean, unfortunately. Could you rephrase it?

Answer (score 2):

Windows ME has HLT support -- does your software run under that OS?

Windows ME is still the Windows 95 kernel underneath, technically, so I suspect it might run your software fine.

Comment: I do believe this is the first business case I have ever seen for ME, well done!

Comment: Another is if you like your mouse pointer to not flicker like it does in Windows 95-98 ^^

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_performance_improve_win9x.html is what I followed when I needed to create a windows 95 virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that win95 can't manage the CPU. For that reason programs like CPUIDLE or DOSIDLE were invented.

DosIdle will work in a virtualized dos 6.22 enviroment. 
CPUIDLE doesn't work in a esx4.0 win95 VM. It generates general exeption errors.

The workaround for now is to limit the CPU resources.
When you check the performance graph in VMware, Vmware displays that the win 95 vm claims 100% of the allocated CPU but uses 40% of it.

I'm pesimistic about finding a solution... but if anyone  has one..... :-)